# Can a chatbot which is published in mutiple facebook pages know what facebook pages the user chats from?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

Hi i have a bot made from Bot framework V4 using c# that is deployed in azure bot service. I am planning to use the bot with multiple Facebook pages. How can i check which Facebook page the user chats from? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can have one bot and use this bot with multiple Facebook pages. You will need to store page_access_token for each page and response messages with right page_access_token.

You can map the page ids to the access token associated with each page id and store them in an object:

```
const accessTokens = {
    myPageId1: 'myPageAccessToken1',
    myPageId2: 'myPageAccessToken2',
}
```

When you get a callback on webhook, you get a page entry and page id. To check which Facebook page the user chats are coming from, you will need to access the page id.

```
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {  

  let body = req.body;

  // Checks this is an event from a page subscription
  if (body.object === 'page') {

    // Iterates over each entry - there may be multiple if batched
    body.entry.forEach(function(entry) {
       // Get the pageId
        const pageID = pageEntry.id;
        .....
        .....
```

If you want to send a message to a specific page, then you will have to call the Facebook Send API and pass the corresponding page_access_token in the response request.

Comment: If the above answer was helpful, can you accept the answer so that it helps others?Thanks